# How to store values to a file in shell script when executing the shell script from python file?

Tags: python, bash, shell, random

I need to trigger a shell script from a python file. That shell script needs to execute a few commands and store the data in another file.

**Problem**:
I'm able to trigger the shell script from python but the commands getting executed inside the shell script is giving empty response and storing "Cg==" in respective file.

**Shell script: randscript.sh**

Generating random value and storing it to newfile.

```
echo Pass = $(echo $RANDOM | base64 | head -c 20)>>newfile
```

**Python: randfile.py**

Executing python file to trigger the shell script.

```
import os
import subprocess
def rand_func():
  try:
    path = '/home/ubuntu/execution'
    os.chdir(path)
    script_exec = subprocess.call(['sh','./randscript.sh'])
    print(script_exec)
    return True
  except Exception as err:
    print("Exception")
    return False
func_exec = rand_func()
```

Note: When the command was executed manually, it is returning the expected value (giving random value). But via python script, it is returning "Cg=="(which is a newline character).
Could anyone please help me to understand this?

Comment: Try to add ```source ~/.bashrc``` at the first line of you shell script.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using a version of Python prior to 3.5 you could adapt this:

```
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir('/home/ubuntu/execution')

r = subprocess.run(['/bin/sh', './randscript.sh'], capture_output=True)
print(r.stdout.decode())
```

I assume that your shell script emits the relevant output to the standard output stream.

Since posting this answer there's been an edit to the question. The script does **not** emit anything to the standard output stream. Therefore, my answer will not work. By adding:

```
cat newfile
```

...to the end of the script, this will work.

Another (better) option would be:

```
echo Pass = $(echo $RANDOM | base64 | head -c 20) | tee -a newfile
```